# Android | Google Maps api key and self signed certificate conflict

Tags: java, android, google-maps, ssl

after a lot of wasted time I've discovered that my google maps api key conflict with my self signed ssl certificate.

This is my method to trust the cert

```
public static void trustSelfSignedSSL() {

        try {
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return hostname.equals(Config.HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_URL);
                    //System.out.println("*************################### " + hostname);
                    //return true;
                }
            });

            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

            Context appContext = HBGApplication.context;
            AssetManager assets = appContext.getAssets();
            InputStream caInput = assets.open(Config.HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_ASSETS_FILE);
            Certificate ca;
            try {
                ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
                System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
            } finally {
                caInput.close();
            }

            String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);


            String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(keyStore);

            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(
                    context.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (Exception e) { // should never happen
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If I comment this method maps works correctly.
I've tried to verify google maps endpoint in the verify method but it seems it never enters in this method for maps.

So my question is: how can I use my self signed certificate for services communication excluding the maps service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution:

```
protected static Certificate ca;

/**
     * set self signed certificate to trust
     */
    public static void trustSelfSignedSSL() {

        try {
            // set hostname verifier to check hostname validity
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return hostname.equals(Config.HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_URL) || hostname.equals(Config.HTTPS_GOOGLE_URL);
                }
            });

            // load certificate
            hbgCa = getCert();

            // add certificate to key store
            if (null != hbgCa) {
                String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
                KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
                keyStore.load(null, null);
                keyStore.setCertificateEntry("hbgCa", hbgCa);

                String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
                TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
                tmf.init(keyStore);

                SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
//          HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(createSslSocketFactory());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { // should never happen
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    /**
     * create a custom sslsocketfactory to trust server connections
     *
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private static SSLSocketFactory createSslSocketFactory() throws Exception {
        TrustManager[] byPassTrustManagers = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {

                // Loading the CA cert
                if (null == ca) {
                    ca = getCert();
                }

                for (X509Certificate cert : chain) {

                    // check if the certificate is the selfsigned trusted one
                    if (verifiyCertificate(ca, cert)) {
                        return;
                    }
                    // check if current certificate belongs to google
                    if (cert.getIssuerX500Principal().getName().equals("CN=Google Internet Authority G2,O=Google Inc,C=US")) {
                        return;
                    }
                }

        // if none certificate trusted throw certificate exception to tell to not trust connection
                throw new CertificateException();
            }
        }
        };

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, byPassTrustManagers, new SecureRandom());
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    }


    /**
     * verifiy a certificate against the other
     */
    private static boolean verifiyCertificate(Certificate cert1, Certificate cert2) {
        try {
            cert1.verify(cert2.getPublicKey());
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * load and return selfsigned local cert
     *
     * @return
     */
    private static Certificate getCert() {

        try {
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            Context appContext = HBGApplication.getWrapperContext();
            AssetManager assets = appContext.getAssets();
            InputStream caInput = assets.open(Config.HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_ASSETS_FILE);
            Certificate ca;

            try {
                return cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            } catch (CertificateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                caInput.close();
            }

            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

To avoid the default SSLSocketFactory we have the opportunity to implement our custom TrustManager.
Because I'm developing client side, my app should check for server identity into the checkServerTrusted method.
In this method we get our certificate and we try to verify it against all the chain of server's received certificates.
If verification fails an exception is throwned, so we can throw manually a CertificateException that indicates the certificate is not accepted. 
Initially I've downloaded  the google certificate and added it to the certs queue, but when his validity expires my app would not work anymore. So I've decided to check if the name of the cert's IssuerX500Principal matches with the google's one.

Now I can connect to my server and I can use google services.
I've tried changing the cert with another one for test purpose and the connection is not trusted anymore, so I think it works well.

If anyone can suggest me some errors, it would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution inspired by this link

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/11/how-to-setup-custom-sslsocketfactorys-trustmanager-per-each-url-connection.html

It suggests to add a custom SslSocketFactory with a TrustManager

Comment: Obviously after that is a good thing to verify that the google hostname in the verify method of the HostnameVerifier, that  should look like this

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10791205)

Comment: Ok, i'm working on the right solution, when available i'll post it :)